# Manipulating data using hash

Tags: php, javascript

I have been creating an image viewer using jQuery and I have managed to get the image to show dynamically by using ajax to call my PHP code to get a new id of a image. When the user clicks on the button the image is shown with its relevant information, however if they navigate back only the image is changed as the other information is not saved within the hash.

I tried using an ajax post call to get the information of the hashed id however when I do this it recycles through the images like a look and this is not what I want. My code is below:

**HTML**

```
<img id="design" alt="" width="300" height="300"  /><br>
<span id="lblName" name="lblName"></span><br>
<input type="button" id="GetImage" value="Get Image" />
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

if (document.location.hash) {
     updateImage();
}

$("#GetImage").click(function() {

     $.ajax({ //Make the Ajax Request
         type: "POST",
         url: "testimagelook.php", //file name
         success: function(server_response){
            $.getJSON("testimagelook.php", function(data) {             
            var id = data.id;
            document.location.hash = id;
            $("#lblName").html(data.name);
            $("#lblRating").html(data.average + " (" + data.votes + ") (<a href='User.php?uid=" + data.userid + "'>" + data.username + "</a>)");

            });
         }
     });
});

$(window).bind('hashchange',function(){
       updateImage();
});

function updateImage() {
     var id = document.location.hash.substring(1); // remove #
     $('#design').attr('src','img/boxes/'+id+'.png');
}
});
```

The PHP file returns a random row from the database in JSON format.

**EDIT**

The following function (updateImage()) has been changed but is not working:

```
function updateImage() {
     var id = document.location.hash.substring(1); // remove #


     if(known_images[id]==null){
        $.ajax({ //Make the Ajax Request
             type: "POST",
             url: "testimagelook.php", //file name
             data: {boxid: id},
             success: function(server_response){
                $.getJSON("testimagelook.php", function(data) {             
                var id = data.id;

                known_images[id] = [];
                known_images[id] ['name'] = data.name;
                known_images[id] ['average'] = data.average;
                known_images[id] ['votes'] = data.votes;
                known_images[id] ['username'] = data.username;
                known_images[id] ['userid'] = data.userid;

                });
             }
         });
     }

     $('#design').attr('src','img/boxes/'+id+'.png');
     $("#lblName").html(known_images[id]['name']);
     $('#lblRating').html(known_images[id] ['average'] + " (" + known_images[id] ['votes'] + ") (<a href='User.php?uid=" + known_images[id] ['userid'] + "'>" + known_images[id] ['username'] + "</a>)");
}
```

Comment: Why are you making two subsequent Ajax requests to the same URL (one with POST, one with GET)?

Comment: @Bergi I am currently only using one POST request but if I click my browsers back button the only information that i can get is the id (from the hash in the URL) and therefor would have to do another Ajax request to get the rest of the information for this ID.

Comment: No your using TWO `$.ajax` being ONE and `$.getJSON` being another (most likely to respond the same data). I guess what you meant to use is: `var data = $.parseJSON(server_response);`instead

Comment: Im not too sure i have never used it in that way before.

Comment: well, sorry pal, but then you did it wrong all the time :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the most simple approach would be to add

```
var known_images = [];
```

to your javascript and for every ajax request you add:

```
// to be added at success: // at the end of your code!
known_images[id]= [];
known_images[id] ['lbl'] = data.name;
known_images[id] ['rating'] = data.average + " (" + data.votes + ") (<a href='User.php?uid=" + data.userid + "'>" + data.username + "</a>)";
// now all the information is chached in the browser
```

now in your updateImage function you can add

```
$("#lblName").html(known_images[id]['lbl']);
$("#lblRating").html(known_images[id]['rating');
```

to update those informations too from the array of known images

## [EDIT]

to reduce the amount of data stored in known_images you can
easily use

```
known_images.shift();
```

to delete the FIRST item from that array, so is you want to limit the array to a amximum length of say 100 entries you can add this:

```
if(known_images.length >100)
    known_images.shift();
```

right after adding a new id to said array in your "success:" - part of your ajax call

## [EDIT II]

you still got your ajax requests wrong, you overwrite your ajax request with the inner getJSON call

as an example here's your updateImage function without the second request:

```
function updateImage() {
    var id = document.location.hash.substring(1); // remove #

    if(known_images[id]==null){
        $.ajax({ //Make the Ajax Request
            type: "POST",
            url: "testimagelook.php", //file name
            data: {boxid: id},
            success: function(server_response)
            {
                // Now just parse server_response into data without requesting NEW data like you did in your code!
                var data = $.parseJSON(server_response);
                var id = data.id;

                known_images[id] = [];
                known_images[id] ['name'] = data.name;
                known_images[id] ['average'] = data.average;
                known_images[id] ['votes'] = data.votes;
                known_images[id] ['username'] = data.username;
                known_images[id] ['userid'] = data.userid;
                // mind the parentheses here
            }
        });
    }
    $('#design').attr('src','img/boxes/'+id+'.png');
    $("#lblName").html(known_images[id]['name']);
    $('#lblRating').html(known_images[id] ['average'] + " (" + known_images[id] ['votes'] + ") (<a href='User.php?uid=" + known_images[id] ['userid'] + "'>" + known_images[id] ['username'] + "</a>)");
}
```

Comment: This method would work but surely this would take up a lot of data on the users front end? If the user goes through 2000 images that means that it will have to hold 2000 id, names, averages, votes etc... surely this is not very good for performance?

Comment: you could add some more lines of code to reduce the array to a max size of say.. the last 100 entries. The other option would be to send another ajax call to your website and asking for the informations about a certain already known ID, that will reduce the amount of data on the client side but will increase the server load by the same amount.

Comment: Do you have any idea what out of the two options you have given would be the best for performance?

Comment: well a local stored array is performing a lot faster than an ajax call, for both, client and server! But you're right to assume, that some thousand entries in such array could clog the clients machine quite a bit, so you should take care of that by reducing the array size I'll post an example in a few

Comment: Thats great thanks. Yes an example would be great if you could provide one. Also i have set this up in my application and it is working great, however if the user enters a url of an image that has not already been saved the image is not shown. I need this functionality to work as my users may copy and paste the url to friends to check out.

Comment: that can be achieved with a simple check on that array for example. `if(known_images[unknownID]==null){$.ajax({/*get it here*/})};`

Comment: I cant get this to work with url's that have been copied and pasted. I have edited my code to show what i have added. Please tell me where i am going wrong

Comment: well.. my post wasn't the correct answer nor being helpful? that makes me sad.